# @ifpackageloaded If \RenewDocumentCommand Else \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: pdftex, xparse

Hello (sorry for the strange title), I wanted to know how I can define a command with `\NewDocumentCommand` if a package hasn't been loaded and if it has than I want to redefine it with `\RenewDocumentCommand`. Any suggestions? (I wouldn't mind expl3 commands if it makes it simplier.)
And btw. I don't want a solution like this:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{...}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand\whatever{...}{
        code A
    }
}{
    \NewDocumentCommand\whatever{...}{
        code A
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something where I don't have to write the part 'code A' twice (arguments are also the same). :D

Comment: You can do `\@ifpackageloaded{...}{\RenewDocumentCommand}{\NewDocumentCommand}\whatever{...}{code A}`

Comment: This works... wow so simple? Have to try it immediately.

Comment: Tysm. Sounds like a stupid question afterwards tbh. I used the solution from @ Phelype Oleinik and have nothing to complain about it :D.

Comment: @Yumina弓那Nirvalen Not stupid at all.  I added an answer with a bit of explanation.  Glad it helped :)

Comment: @ campa \providecommand wouldn't redefine the command in the first case.  Although you could `\providecommand` and then immediately `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\@ifpackageloaded{...}
  {\RenewDocumentCommand}
  {\NewDocumentCommand} \whatever {...}
    {
      code A
    }
```

then `\@ifpackageloaded` will do the test, and leave either `\RenewDocumentCommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` in the input stream, which will be followed by the usual arguments.

This is a common trick when programming lower-level code.  For example (randomly chosen), `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` and `\tl_gset_rescan:Nnn` are defined like:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn
  { \__tl_set_rescan:NNnn \tl_set:No }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_gset_rescan:Nnn
  { \__tl_set_rescan:NNnn \tl_gset:No }
```

they use the same internal `\__tl_set_rescan:NNnn`, with a different first argument that does `\tl_set:No` or `\tl_gset:No`, saving you from a lot of code repetition.

Comment: Just a 'tiny tiny bit'. That explanation really helped to understand it. <3

Comment: In fact it makes the code a tiny tiny bit slower (during execution), the version with code repetition would save one step of expansion (but be much less maintainable).

Comment: @Skillmon Would it?  (not that it matters but) `\@ifpackageloaded` would take the same amount of work to expand, then the difference would be between (say) `\@firstoftwo{\singletoken}{\singletoken}` and `\@firstoftwo{a whole bunch of tokens}{a whole bunch of tokens}`.  `\<Whatever>DocumentCommand` would then behave the same in either case.

Comment: Oh, then I just parsed your text wrong. Yes, the `\@ifpackageloaded` code in your answer is faster this way. I thought you meant the `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` code, as that one is slower the way it is implemented. Sorry for the noise :)

Comment: @Skillmon Ah, yes, of course.  My writing was not at its brightest either :)  I removed that last part.  Was just making it confusing